# What is the idiomatic way to print a Vec as a string?

Tags: string, vector, rust

Updating my code to the new nightlies and it seems like they've gotten rid of to_string() for std::Vec

```
src/rust_mnemonic.rs:100:39: 100:50 error: type `collections::vec::Vec<&str>` does not implement any method in scope named `to_string`
rc/rust_mnemonic.rs:100     println!("mnemonic: {}", mnemonic.to_string());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `:?` specifier, which uses the `Debug` trait.

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![0u8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

If you want it as a `String`, then you can use [`format!`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.format!.html):

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![0u8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let s = format!("{:?}", v);
    println!("-->{}<--", s);
}
```

Comment: @leshow Some motivation/explanation of the `{:?}` specifier is available in the [Show stabilization RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0504-show-stabilization.md).

Comment: how about to actually convert a Vec<u8> to a string?